# How to detect if a Type supports equaility with no == operator?

Tags: c#, .net

So Int32 does not have an == operator but this is valid code

```
bool y = 6 == 5;
```

This is because Int32 is part of the primitive set of types. It effectively compiles to CEQ in IL.

So given a Type (with reflection) how can it be determined that that type supports CEQ when it has no == operator?

Comment: Why? What are you trying to do?

Comment: IL weaving. I want to compare two instances of the same type.

Comment: Note that CEQ supports reference types too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spec says (§7.10):

> The predefined integer comparison operators are:
>
> ```
> bool operator ==(int x, int y);
> bool operator ==(uint x, uint y);
> bool operator ==(long x, long y);
> bool operator ==(ulong x, ulong y);
> ```
>
> The predefined floating-point comparison operators are:
>
> ```
> bool operator ==(float x, float y);
> bool operator ==(double x, double y);
> ```
>
> The predefined decimal comparison operators are:
>
> ```
> bool operator ==(decimal x, decimal y);
> bool operator !=(decimal x, decimal y);
> ```
>
> The predefined boolean equality operators are:
>
> ```
> bool operator ==(bool x, bool y);
> bool operator !=(bool x, bool y);
> ```
>
> Every enumeration type implicitly provides the following predefined
>   comparison operators:
>
> ```
> bool operator ==(E x, E y);
> bool operator !=(E x, E y);
> ```

Note that `decimal.operator ==` is a normal method, not a built-in operator.  I'm not sure why it's listed there.